# Will movlw PORTB, movwf PORTC work

Tags: assembly, microcontroller, pic, microchip

Goodday to you all;

I started with programming of a pic for 2 days now;
And have a question about assembly, i have a PIC 16F887a on a EASYPIC7 (development) board.
I try to read the buttons on PORTB and direct them to PORTC.

So i tought i do:

```
movlw PORTB ; mov value of PORTB to "W file" (depents on which switches are pressed)
```

;and direcly after that

```
movwf PORTC ; mov value of "W file" to PORTC and should light up the led's
```

But no luck,
Can this work (and did i setup the PIC wrong) or can this not work and if so why not ?

Comment: Have you set up PORTB to be inputs and PORTC to be outputs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`movlw` places a literal value in WREG. This means that the value is a constant, determined at assembly time. `movlw PORTB` places the low byte of the address of PORTB in WREG, not the value of PORTB. To get the value, you need to use the `movf` instruction.

```
movf PORTB, W ; Place the value of PORTB in WREG
movwf PORTC   ; Store WREG into PORTC
```